# Event data with @HostListener() decorator

Tags: angular

How do I get the event data (i.e. `$event`) I get here:

```
<button (click)="doSomething($event)">
```

Here instead?:

```
@HostListener('click') onClick($event) {
    // TypeError: $data is undefined
}
```

It's undefined... `:(`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I presume that your HostListener is part of some kind of directive that should be used on button probably? Than you got to do this:
-- click-me.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appClickMe]'
})

export class ClickMeDirective {

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: Event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

and then you use this directive on

```
<button appClickMe > Click me</button>
```

and this will work. But this is also overkill, you dont need to do that when you have angular click listener:

```
<button (click)="doSomething($event)">
```

and in your .ts file:

```
doSomething($event) {
    console.log($event);
}
```

hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
@HostListener('click') onClick($event) {
  ...
}
```

to this

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event) {
  ...
}
```